# Firestore security rules: How to validate that a field is undefined?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When a user signs up and they initialise their data in firestore, I want to validate that they aren't attempting to set their role (i.e. so they're not setting it to 'admin' for example).

I tried to write this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow create: if (signedInAs(userId) && !request.resource.data.role) || isAdmin();
  ...
```

...but I just see "Property role is undefined on object."

Is there a way to do this safely? Or does this mean I should always be initialising expected fields, even if it's just to the empty string? That doesn't seem to quite fit with the philosophy of NoSQL?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `in` operator to find out if a property of an object doesn't exist.

```
!("role" in request.resource.data)
```

This yields a boolean.  See it in the rules API docs for the [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) type.

Comment: It only works well when I fetch the individual document, but not when I fetch collection :/

Comment: @DariuszBacinski What do you mean by fetching collection? For that you would have 'exists' (for a document to exist under that collection). I don't see the relevance of your comment with regard to the question or answer. Educate me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `writeFields` if other solutions do not work.

```
!("role" in request.writeFields)
```